# How can I add css/image on webpage using django?

Tags: python, css, django

I put the image("hi.png") and css file in /home/user1/djangoblog/blog/static

In templates i have `<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/hi.png" />`

I edited the settings.py =>

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = "/static/"

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    "/home/user1/djangoblog/blog/static/",)
```

The web page source returns =>

`<div><img src="/static/images/a.jpg" /></div>`

If the views.py => The image is not displayed on the web page.

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
#return render_to_response('current_datetime.html', {"foo": now}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
t = loader.get_template('current_datetime.html')
c = Context({'foo': now})
return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

But if the views.py => it displays the images on the web page.

```
return render_to_response('current_datetime.html', {"foo": now}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

It looks like it's a problem with HttpResponse or RequestContext. How can i fix this problem with HttpResponse or RequestContext?

Comment: I don't know why you keep getting voted down. Seems like a totally legitimate question since it's not always immediately apparent that you have to add the context processor in addition to adding staticfilses to your installed apps.

Comment: Use `RequestContext` instead of `Context` otherwise you don't get any of the variables created by `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`.

Comment: I can't understand. What's the problem if i use Context instead of RequestContext? What do you mean by variables created by `TEMPLATE_COnTEXT_PROCESSORS`

Comment: My advice: stop right now, read the docs, read the Django book. Your question and subsequent comments to answers have revealed a lack of understanding of key concepts involved in creating a Django site. I'm not saying that to discourage you, but you need to wrap your head around this basic stuff before you move any further.

Comment: @guru: the variables that you need, like MEDIA_URL, etc. are all created by context processors listed in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS. Those variables are ONLY available if you use `RequestContext` instead of `Context`. Use `Context` *only* when you *don't* need those variables. Okay? Seems like you are digging yourself deeper and deeper into misunderstanding. There's no reason to change your STATIC_URL, there's no reason to use `Context` instead of `RequestContext` and actually you really should just use `render_to_template` or even just `render` unless you have a compelling reason otherwise.

Comment: @ChrisPratt in all honesty, you can happily build Django websites for a long time without really worrying about `Context` or `RequestContext`. Seems like guru's initial problem was the equivalent of a car running out of gas and guru's reaction has been to start taking apart the engine. They're getting way too involved in non-essential details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read the staticfiles docs more carefully.

You specify the absolute path to your static directory with `STATIC_ROOT` and the URL that directory can be accessed at through a browser via `STATIC_URL`. Your main static directory should *never* go in `STATICFILES_DIRS`. That setting is only to allow you to specify additional directories that should be processed while running the `collectstatic` management command.

In general, you *never* use your actual static directory. In development Django serves files from each app's `static` directory and any directories in `STATICFILES_DIRS` (excluding the main `static` directory). In production, you run the `collectstatic` management command and then setup your main webserver (Apache, Nginx, etc) to serve files from `STATIC_ROOT`. Django **never** serves anything from the main `static` directory (`STATIC_ROOT`).

Comment: I'm running with `python manage.py runserver` , not using apache, so what will be the settings.py? Can you post a correct settings.py for css/image/javascript use?

Comment: It depends on your environment, but typically `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')` and `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

Comment: I used it, `import os                                         STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static') 
STATIC_URL = '/static/'` But still didn't work. Its not getting the static/ folder, In template, `{{ STATIC_ROOt }}` and `{{ STATIC_URL }}` prints nothing.

Comment: I updated the original post/question, see that again to understand.

Comment: `STATIC_URL` should be the path off http://localhost:8000 or the URL to your static server if you're using a separate server for static resources (i.e. `http://static.mydomain.com`). You have the physical path on your hard drive.

Comment: Should STATIC_URL be `/home/user1/djangoblog`? or `STATIC_URL='http://localhost:8000'` The static folder is in `/home/user1/djangoblog/blog/`

Comment: *Most likely* `STATIC_URL` should be exactly what I said it should be previously `'/static/'`.

Comment: Is this correct now? `STATIC_ROOT = '/home/user1/djangoblog/blog/static' ; STATIC_URL = "/static/"` still it doesn't work. I think, STATIC_ROOT is not set correctly, in template, `{{ STATIC_ROOT }}` it doesn't print anything.

Comment: You never use `{{ STATIC_ROOT }}` in your template, only `{{ STATIC_URL }}`. Don't worry about STATIC_ROOT, you don't use it, the staticfiles app does.

Comment: See the last sentence of my answer: "Django *never* serves anything from the main `static` directory (`STATIC_ROOT`)." You can't directly put files there, it's only a place for `collectstatic` to dump stuff so your webserver in production can serve them. You must put files in one of your apps' `static` directories or in an *entirely* separate directory (not `MEDIA_ROOT` nor `STATIC_ROOT`) and then add that directory to `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, I updated the original post/question, see that again to understand

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the problem is that you don't have the staticfiles context processor in your settings file. That's the reason that `/static/` isn't being inserted where you've put `{{ STATIC_URL }}`.

It's as simple as putting

```
'django.core.context_processors.static',
```

Into the list of context processors (`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`) in your settings.py file.

## Update

> I added this in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS but still that didn't work. – guru 3 hours ago

Adding `'django.core.context_processors.static'` to the list of context processors **did fix** your problem because as you can now see, it is inserting the value for `STATIC_URL` wherever it sees `{{ STATIC_URL }}` in your templates. The error is that you've changed the value of `STATIC_URL` to `"/home/user1/djangoblog/blog/static/"` probably because you've been confused by some of the answers here.

Change the value of `STATIC_URL` **back** to `'/static/'` so that line should read

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

That will fix your problem.

**Django templates simply put whatever is in the variable into the template**. They don't care what it is or what it represents. If the value of STATIC_URL is `/home/user1/djangoblog/blog/static/` then it dutifully inserts `/home/user1/djangoblog/blog/static/` wherever it sees `{{ STATIC_URL }}` which is why you are seeing

> `<img src="/home/user1/djangoblog/blog/static/images/a.jpg" />`

whenever it renders the template containing `<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/a.png" />`

Comment: Where would i put this line? `'django.core.context_processors.static',` in INSTALLED_APPS ? If i add it in INSTALLED_APPS i got error, `Error: No module named static`

Comment: I added this in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` but still that didn't work.

Comment: I updated the original post/question, see that again to understand.

Comment: Looks like you messed things up worse. I'll update my original answer.

Comment: I updated the original post/question, see that again to understand